# DeprecationWarning: crypto.createCipher is deprecated in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, cryptography, compiler-warnings

I'm getting the below warning while building my node service.

```
DeprecationWarning: crypto.createCipher is deprecated.
```

I have crypto npm module installed in my service.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
```

But the thing is I'm nowhere in my service using the **crypto.createCipher** function.
The only function i'm using in my service from crypto module is `crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');`

**What i have tried**

I have tried to reinstall the crypto module with the latest version (does not fix the warning)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use this [crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto) npm package.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

### Fix

You need to use the inbuilt `crypto` package. No need to install it. It's built-in by default.

Please remove the `crypto` npm package from your `package.json`

```sh
npm remove --save crypto
```

Comment: i see crypto-random-string module, whose index have const crypto = require('crypto');

Comment: Also i remove npm remove --save crypto and removed from my package.json, but the deprecation message is still there

Comment: after i remove the crypto module, the randomBytes generation function is still working but the warning message about crypto.createCipher is deprecated is still there.

Comment: Which `node` version are you using? `node --version`

Comment: i'm using  v12.14.1

Comment: I have downloaded node version `v12.14`. I don't get a deprecation message. Are you sure that you recompiled your typescript project?

Comment: It is possible that one of your dependencies is using `crypto.createCipher()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223510/discussion-between-the-joker-and-a1300).